# Увеличивание блока по ширине в зависимости от контента

Tags: css, css3

Всем привет.

Такая задача, нужно в зависимости от контента - увеличивать ширину родителя. Средствами ксс это как реализовать?..

```css
.box1{
 min-width: 400px;
 width: 400px;
 height:50px;
 border: 1px solid orange;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.box2{
 border: 1px solid red;
 color: black;
 width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
   fsdfsdfsdsd
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Не задавайте `width` у обоих блоков, так они станут по ширине контента, `min-width` можно оставить.

Comment: Если не давать минимальную ширину - блок по дефолту занимает 100% ширины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Увеличивание блока по ширине в зависимости от контента

Например так (контент 50 символов):

```css
.box1{
    display: inline-block;
 height:50px;
 border: 1px solid orange;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.box2{
 border: 1px solid red;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
     Тут Ваш какой-то контент в 50 символов.
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque debitis beatae, recusandae ipsa sint fugit natus consectetur esse quos eligendi, quia nam. Dolorum ipsam animi optio ratione eum fuga molestiae illum saepe, impedit unde eos quasi exercitationem omnis magni itaque doloremque nemo at deleniti sint fugit quod, officia modi. At.
        </div>
</div>
```

Например так (контент 5 символов):

```css
.box1{
    display: inline-block;
 height:50px;
 border: 1px solid orange;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.box2{
 border: 1px solid red;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
     Lore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Текущие технологии располагают к тому, чтобы увеличивать контейнеры не в ширину, а в высоту - почему бы не воспользоваться этим? Ширину контейнера задавать фиксированную или зависящую от ширины окна (резиновую или адаптивную), а высоту определять количеством контента. Без каких-либо костылей.

В теории вы можете расширять внешний контейнер в js, работая с шириной и высотой внутреннего контейнера. Но, опять же - в теории. Придется городить костыли, хотя можно обойтись меньшей кровью - изменив дизайн.

Не стесняйтесь объяснять дизайнеру, почему его задумки тяжело осуществимы в вебе, и как можно найти компромисс между дизайнерской идеей и реализацией в коде.

Comment: Средствами жс можно в пару строк решить вопрос, взять ширину потомка и дать её родителю. Но вот думал можно ли через ксс или нет